# access sub-elements of an array in php foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a cURL command from an API which outputs JSON for me:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url.com/Search/search/xref?user=[{%22USER%22:%22userName%22}]");
```

I then use PHP's jsondecode on the output:

```
$json = json_decode($answerSearch, true);
```

and my console's response tab gives me this for `print_r($json);`:

```
Array (
 [Result] => Array
        (
            [Data] => Array
                (
                    [ReqCompany] => ACME
                    [ReqLocation] => 
                    [Dot] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ComID] => 20388417
                                    [FavoriteColor] => Blue

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [ComID] => 20388418
                                    [FavoriteColor] => Pink
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [ComID] => 20388419
                                    [FavoriteColor] => Red
                                )

                        )

                    [XREFSearchOperation] => Exact
                )

        )

)
```

How do I write a foreach loop to go through each element of this array and output each `[FavoriteColor]'?  I've done this many times with a simple array, but never a multi-dimensional one.

I've tried this:

```
foreach ($json as $i) {
  echo $i['FavoriteColor']; 
}
```

but my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$json` is an array of only one item `Result`, another array, which in turn only has one item, another array `Data` etc.  `Data` has multiple items, one of them being `Dot` which holds the array you want. You need to `foreach` over the array farther into the array:

```
foreach ($json['Result']['Data']['Dot'] as $i) {
  echo $i['FavoriteColor']; 
}
```

Comment: Beautiful - I wasn't sure how to keep drilling down into these array elements.  Thank you!  This works perfectly.